# Aria 2 disconnected in AriaNG

Tags: raspberry-pi

I installed Aria 2 and the ArianN graphic interface https://hub.docker.com/r/p3terx/aria2-pro, but I still have Aria diconnected. Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.